# SSIS dynamic connection string not found

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am attempting to create a package that will use dynamically-generated connection strings.

Project-level parameter of "ServerName":

```
@[$Project::ServerName] = DEV01
```

Package-level Variable of "MasterDBConnectionString":

```
"Data Source="+@[$Project::ServerName]+";Initial Catalog=master;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"
```

In my Execute SQL Task, I am using an expression to use the @[User::MasterDBConnectionString] for the Connection property.  I have set DelayValidation=TRUE.

It bombs every time.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: SSIS package "H:\Source Control\KBADataWarehouse\trunk\SSIS_WJK\KBA_DW_DimCreation\KBA_DW_DimCreation\Package.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0xC001000E at Package: The connection "Data Source=DEVELOPER16;Initial Catalog=master;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.

Comment: Also DEV01 == DEVELOPER16 (just a naming convention change)

Comment: I do not believe my connection string is incorrect.  I even added "Driver={SQL Driver};" and it did not work.

Comment: https://goo.gl/photos/doUVMw8xYihPVgnP9

Comment: https://goo.gl/photos/ipzJTFD1cU4FuTsLA

Comment: If you hard-code that connection string, does it work?

Comment: Tab... I just tried that, where I hard-coded the connection string in the Connection property of the task and it did not work

Comment: Well then, there definitely is a problem with your connection string.  Was the error message the same with the hard-coded string?

Comment: Yes, same error message

Comment: Sounds like you have some investigating to do then, since none of us can see your network.  My first guess is the target server doesn't exist, or can't be seen from where you're executing the package.

Comment: Well, the server is my local machine, so I guess the package can't see it; however, is there a way to set a default connection at the package-level?